# Minimizing the JSF ViewState for large page

Tags: performance, jsf, session

I'm currently developing a **JSF** application with **single-page-per-app** design, such like in desktop apps. the sections are placed in tabs, and every suboperation, such as editing or inserting item, in displayed in dialog.

What is becoming the issue, it is both the size of ViewState and the processing time of each request. At the moment, the initial size of ViewState in POST is 200kb (and the compression is enabled). The request last from 200 to 400 ms (on my own machine, with no users except me).

Setting state saving to session greatly reduces the request, but greatly increases the processing time - now it's from 350 to 600 ms. Because this is intranet application, net transfer is cheap, so better to send more that process longer.

I don't know how to deal with that problem. Is it possible to reduce the space consumed by JSF components? Most of them don't change on every click, but they seem to be deserialized and processed anyway. Or should I throw out every data (such as dictionaries for drop-down lists) from JSF beans and use intensive caching in service layer? Or there are other options/tricks/improvements I could use?

Comment: Personaly I find 200 to 400 ms quiet reasonable times. 
But why do you need a signle page per app? I'm just curious to know the reason behind this. I'm not saying it is incorrect or not good. Are you using ajax requests? Or do you reload the whole page avary time you perform an action?

Comment: It doesn't matter how much is updated, even the simplest click that updates only single button causes the whole view processing to launch, so I think this is view store-restore issues. Single page is simply requirements, so that there would be no page navigation inside single app, which is launched inside other container.

Comment: I wonder if it would make a difference if you get your app to work with [Stateless JSF](http://www.industrieit.com/blog/2011/11/stateless-jsf-high-performance-zero-per-request-memory-overhead/)?

Comment: I don't know if it would work with PrimeFaces and does it have licence compatibile with company policies. The design from scratch would be not acceptable and in that case it could be as good done with JS libraries

Comment: Did you test it in a sane test server which simulates the production server as close as possible? A bit decent webserver (multicore, gigs of RAM, SSD, RAID, etc) is many times faster than your own machine. Given that it's intranet, I'd also opt for client side state saving.

Comment: I don't have access to such machines, my desktop computer is slower than those, but I have also only 1 concurrent user (me) and not 100... It is actually intriguing to me why restoring view state from request could be faster that from session...

Answer (score 0):

As you have already figured out, the View State of the entire form is being serialized on every ansynchronous post back so that the server and client can stay in sync.  ASP.NET works in pretty much the exact same way.

The Primefaces team has added functionality to many of their Ajax enabled components that allow for Partial Page posts.

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1842

The `partialSubmit` property will only serialize form elements that are specified in the `process` attribute of the component or `<p:ajax>`.  Of course this is only a solution for Primefaces components, but it has significantly reduced the request size on some of my larger JSF pages.

Comment: I've tested  `process`attribute with p:ajax, but the whole ViewState is sent anyway...

Comment: @lechlukasz And you set `partialSubmit` to true?

Comment: partialSubmit is undocumented for p:ajax, but it is 'compiling' however I see no difference

Comment: even table sorting causes full ViewState sending so this feature of PrimeFaces isn't working even there where it should out of box...

Comment: @lechlukasz What version of PrimeFaces are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize IFrames and session variables to reduce component trees. Each iframe will maintains its own view. Of course in back end process your application is no longer a single page application. However user will still seamlessly see it as a single age applications.

Comment: This would in my not so humble opinion make application development so much more complex that I would advise against it. Please check if restoring the view-state is the performance killer or processing of the values being sent.

Comment: I used to split-combine-reuse page components using ui:include. Unfortunatelly, the restore view-state take several seconds for my complex page. Converting ui:include to iframe was slightly modify my pages, and increase restore view-state to less than a second. This is a huge improvement I was looking for.